# How to give Different background color for different sections of graph chart.js v 3.8.0

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, chart.js, background-color

I want different colors for different sections of my graph .
It will be more clear in my code and the screen shots that I am sharing .
You are welcome to add your code OR modify code .

as shown in my images . my 0 is at y top and my Y max is at bottom . So when I give background color to chart portion it gives color from the position of 0 . I don't want it to start from 0 , I want to start from Y-max and portion below graph .

MY CODE :

```
    let xValues = \[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45\]
    let yValues = \[1584, 1580, 1576, 1552, 1521, 1552, 1520, 1499, 1485, 1433, 1386, 1329, 1260, 1178, 1084, 981, 870, 756, 644, 538, 441, 355, 282, 222, 172, 133, 102, 77, 59, 44, 33, 25, 10\]

    var markPoint = 21;
    var yMarkPoint = 1400;
    let index = -1;
    var pointFound = false;
    for (var i = 0; i \< xValues.length; i++) {
        if (!pointFound) {
            if (xValues\[i\] == markPoint) {
                yValues\[i\] = yMarkPoint
                index = i
                pointFound = true
                break;
            } else if (xValues\[i\] != markPoint) {
                    if (markPoint \> xValues\[i\] && markPoint \< xValues\[i + 1\]) {
                        xValues.splice(i + 1, 0, markPoint);
                        yValues\[i\] = yMarkPoint
                        yValues.splice(i + 1, 0, yMarkPoint);
                        index = fruits.indexOf(markPoint, 0);
                        pointFound = true
                        break;
                    } else {
                        yValues\[i\] = yMarkPoint
                        index = i
                    }
            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    var data = {
        labels: xValues,
        datasets: \[{
            label: 'Sample Data',
            data: yValues,
            borderColor: "red",
            fill: true,
            tension: 0.4
        }\],
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    Chart.register({
        id: 'lineAlt',
        afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
            var ctx = chart.ctx;
            var xScale = chart.scales.x;
            var yScale = chart.scales.y;

            // 1 x scale unit
            var unitX = xScale.getPixelForValue(1) - xScale.getPixelForValue(0);

            var yTop = yScale.getPixelForValue(yScale.min);
            var yBottom = yScale.getPixelForValue(yScale.max);
            var yMin = yScale.getPixelForValue(800);
            var yTarget = yScale.getPixelForValue(yMarkPoint);

            // Change your color here
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(100,100,100,0.2)';

            // Draw rectangle above y-axis values
            ctx.fillRect(xScale.left, yTop, xScale.right - xScale.left, yMin - yTop);

            // Reset fill style
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
        }
    });

    var config = {
        type: "line",
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: { display: false },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Age'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    reverse: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Risk'
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                annotation: {
                    annotations: {
                        line: {
                            type: 'line',
                            yMin: 800,
                            yMax: 800,
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            borderColor: 'red'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new Chart(ctx, config);
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri2xU.png)

[Work I have done so far ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF3kA.png)